# how to locate new location through marker and the marker location save in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

i want to locate new location in google maps. Is it possible to locate new location through marker and the new location can be save in sqlite datbase? What I mean here is i want the user click the button and then the button will display the location where the button click even the new location can be displayed.

Comment: It's possible refer to the article i googled...so many tutorial out there with  'google maps sqlite' as your search keyword http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/storing-and-retrieving-locations-in-sqlite-from-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Comment: that means every time the user click the button, the new location will be save in sqlite